# Chart not obeying width and height attributes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

[image]

My Morris JS chart is not rendering well inside a bootstrap column, like the documentation tells I gave width and height attributes to the container but the chart is not obeying them.

Does someone have a clue to fix it?

```
var graficoCampanhaefbe = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'graficoCampanhaefbe',  
    data: [{"nome": "Redes Sociais 1459", "destinatarios": "2", "abertos": "4", "clicados": "2", "capturados": "3"}], 
    barColors: ['#00A5DB','#6EA700','#FFB203','#B50000'],
    xkey: 'nome', 
    ykeys: ['destinatarios','abertos', 'clicados', 'capturados'],
    labels: ['Destinatario','Abertos', 'Clicados', 'Capturados'], 
    hideHover: 'always'
});
```

When I set `resize: true` and resize the window the graphic renders just perfect.

[image]

Comment: Please also post the HTML-snippet when referring to a HTML-question.

Answer (score 1):

In your `$(document).ready`, try to trigger a window resize after you initialized your Morris Bar and set your `resize` Morris Bar parameter to true:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var graficoCampanhaefbe = Morris.Bar({...});

    //graficoCampanhaefbe.redraw(); //if needed
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: This does not fix the root of the problem (*before or during* the rendering fase), but it's merely a fix for the outcome (*after* the rendering fase).

Comment: That's what he said: _"When I set resize: true and resize the window the graphic renders just perfect."_

Answer (score 0):

You should add `class="col-xs-12"` to the chart or it's container.

You have not specified a HTML snippet, but it should be the element on which you cast the chart.